# Where is William Finley in Wise Blood?

Tags: cameo, wise-blood

IMDb has [**William Finley**](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0278073/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t35#actor) listed as 'Man (uncredited)' in the [cast list for Wise Blood](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080140/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast).

I have scoured this film in an attempt to find where he appears. I've tried to look at everyone in backgrounds of scenes and crowd shots in an attempt to locate him, but I'm turning up with very vague guesses with no certainty at all. The fact that he is listed simply as 'Man' is frustratingly of no help in identifying him.

I tried searching online and all I primarily end up with obituaries that note that he indeed did appear in the film.

Either he is incredibly hard to discern in his appearance, or he's in plain sight and I somehow failed to recognize him.

Comment: Hopefully this question is okay to ask here. The way I interpreted the do's and don'ts on the Tour and Help Center pages made it sound permissible; if it is inappropriate or should be asked/moved elsewhere, let me know.